# Existe dialeto de LISP/Logo em português?

Tags: lisp, logo

Para criança programar com palavras em inglês podem atrapalhar um pouco para entender bem o que tudo é e faz. Cresci com o Superlogo em holandês. Existem coisas assim em português?

Comment: Talvez o [Portugol](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Portugol)? Não se assemelha ao Lisp ou ao Logo, mas talvez seja útil para o público alvo infantil.

Comment: Parece ser tipo um dialeto de Algol. Muito bom saber que isso existe!

Comment: Uma outra opção é o [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) do MIT, que [parece ter tradução ao português](http://info.scratch.mit.edu/Languages).

Comment: Ótimas referências! Talvez bote como resposta tb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[KTurtle](http://edu.kde.org/kturtle/?site_locale=pt_BR) do *The KDE Education Project* ([documentação](http://docs.kde.org/stable/pt_BR/kdeedu/kturtle/)).

> O KTurtle é um ambiente educativo de programação que usa o TurtleScript, uma linguagem de programação vagamente baseada e inspirada pelo Logo. O objetivo do KTurtle é fazer a programação tão fácil e acessível quanto possível. Isto torna o KTurtle adequado para ensinar às crianças as bases da Matemática, Geometria e... programação. Uma das características principais do TurtleScript é a habilidade de traduzir os comandos no idioma do programador.

---

[Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) do *Massachusetts Institute of Technology* (MIT) ([documentação](http://info.scratch.mit.edu/Languages)).

> Atualmente as pessoas tem acesso a uma inacreditável variedade de jogos interativos, estórias, animações, simulações e outros tipos de mídia interativa e dinâmica em seus computadores, mas para a maioria, estes programas são uma estrada de mão úni ca: você pode apenas ver,clicar e usar o que foi criado por outras pessoas, você não pode projetar e criar seus próprios programas.
>
> Scratch muda isto, ampliando o leque do que você pode pode projetar e criar no computador, tornando fácil a combinação d e graficos, fot    os, musica e sons gerando criações interativas. Com o Scratch, você pode criar personagens que dançam, cantam e interagem uns com outros, ou criar imagens que rodopiem, girem e são animadas em respostas aos movimentos do mouse, ou integrar imagens com efeitos de som e clips de musica para criar um cartão de aniversário par um amigo, ou criar um relatório escolar interativo.

---

[xLogo](http://xlogo.tuxfamily.org/pt/index-pt.html) ([documentação](http://xlogo.tuxfamily.org/pt/xlogo.htm)).

> XLOGO é um interpretador LOGO escrito em java que, atualmente, roda em 8 idiomas: alemão, árabe, francês, inglês, espanhol, português, galês e esperanto. Distribuído sob licença GPL, é um programa ("software") livre e gratuito.

---

[Academia da Tat](http://turtleacademy.com/next//index/pt) ([documentação](http://turtleacademy.com/next/project/doc/pt)).

> Com a Academia da Tat é surpreendentemente fácil iniciar a criar formar incríveis com a Linguagem Logo

---

[SuperLogo](http://projetologo.webs.com/slogo.html) da *Universidade Estadual de Campinas* (UniCamp) ([documentação](http://projetologo.webs.com/logocom.htm)).

> Esta versão gratuita de Logo em português foi desenvolvida pelo Nied da UniCamp com base no MSWLogo (sobre o MSWLogo pode ser interessante também experimentar o FMSLogo, com interfaces em inglês, espanhol, alemão e agora também em português).

---

[wxLogo](http://algol.dcc.ufla.br/%7Ebruno/wxlogo/) da *Universidade Federal de Lavras* (UFLA) ([documentação](http://algol.dcc.ufla.br/%7Ebruno/wxlogo/docs/wxLogo.html)).

> O projeto wxLogo consiste no desenvolvimento de um interpretador LOGO multiplataforma (com versão para Windows e Linux, ao menos).
>
> Este projeto foi criado com a esperança de contruibuir com a redução de custos dos laboratórios de informática de escolas públicas, proporcionando um programa gratuito e que roda num sistema operacional gratuito. O LOGO é muito usado em laboratórios de informática dado que ele estimula o raciocínio lógico dos alunos.

Comment: Você sabe se isso funciona tb no Windows? (uso o Linux pessoalmente, então não preciso, mas pode ser interessante para quem procura...)

Comment: Transformei em *wiki da comunidade*, passemos a manter um só...

Comment: Vi, daí marquei como resposta ;)

Answer (score 4):

Outras alternativas relevantes para iniciar programação com um público alvo infantil ou que não tenha familiaridade com o inglês são:

- [G-Portugol](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-Portugol)

  > G-Portugol é uma linguagem de programação estruturada, totalmente em português, derivada do que é conhecido hoje como "portugol" (uma notação muito utilizada para descrever algoritmos em português de forma livre e espontânea).
  >
  > ```
  > algoritmo OlaMundo;
  > início
  >   imprima("Olá, Mundo!");
  > fim
  > ```

  É interessante notar que a linguagem suporta caracteres acentuados.

---

- [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/) (MIT)

  > Scratch é muito mais acessível que outras linguagens de programação, por se utilizar de uma interface gráfica que permite que programas sejam montados como blocos de montar, lembrando o brinquedo Lego. Utiliza uma sintaxe comum a muitas linguagens de programação. E diferente de outras linguagens, não tem nenhum tipo de pontuação obscura.

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Existe, sim. Lembro de brincar com Logo na escola e era em português. Houve bastante programas assim nos anos 90 e começo de 2000, mas dos ainda ativos o único que me recordo é o KTurtle.

O Kturtle (http://edu.kde.org/kturtle) faz parte de uma suíte de aplicativos educacionais do KDE. Tem uma linguagem baseada no Logo e que pode ser traduzida.
A versão mais recente é para KDE4 e existe tradução para Português!

Comment: Me interessaria muito ver algo desses velhos (aposto que são/eram fechados ou n rodam mais em sistemas de hoje?). Também o Superlogo que mencionei hoje em dia praticamente não dá mais para obter e rodar...